# How to identify which variety of lemon you have?

Tags: seeds, citrus, lemons, variety-selection, cultivar

Last month I decided to start some lemon seedlings from store bought organic lemons imported from Argentina (which for me is a first, usually lemons are imported from Mexico or grown in USA) fast forward a month later, all of the seeds I tried to germinate sprouted and some are doing really well so I'll definitely be keeping some lemon seedlings. However, I got curious on the variety of lemon that I'm currently growing. I did some research and found out that: "Genova and Eureka are the main lemon varieties grown in Argentina" so I'm assuming the ones I bought are either Genova or Eureka, judging from the picture of a lemon from the same batch I germinated seedlings from, could we tell which variety this is?

[image: could we tell from the picture which variety this lemon looks like?]

Comment: It also depends on the citrus trees growing nearby which provide the pollen. Roughly, I would expect more seeds in a fruit that has cross-pollinated with a different variety, if so the new generation would be more diverse.

Answer (score 1):

I can't identify the lemons you have, but it doesn't matter if you just want to know what kind of lemon tree you'll be growing from seed because they don't come true from seed. You may end up with a huge, thorny tree that doesn't produce fruit for years, or if it does, they'e unpalatable, see here [https://www.homestolove.com.au/why-its-not-a-good-idea-to-grow-lemon-trees-from-seeds-12327#:~:text=t%20always%20smart.-,Growing%20lemons%20from%20seed%20isn't%20a%20good%20idea%20as,grown%20by%20budding%20or%20grafting](https://www.homestolove.com.au/why-its-not-a-good-idea-to-grow-lemon-trees-from-seeds-12327#:%7E:text=t%20always%20smart.-,Growing%20lemons%20from%20seed%20isn%27t%20a%20good%20idea%20as,grown%20by%20budding%20or%20grafting).

You might still want to grow them on anyway, just as an experiment to see what you get as they grow on, being aware they might not produce good fruit.

Comment: Hi, I learned that with citrus fruits they're polyembryonic and that sometimes one seed will produce two embryos, one is the result of asexual reproduction ie: nucellar embryo and the other one is zygotic from sexual reproduction. I have several specimens that are twins in this sense so this is more of an experiment than anything else :)

Comment: My apologies  - I was in a rush when I answered you and neglected to add what I usually do in these situations - grow them from seed by all means if you like an experiment,or just for fun to see what you get... I've edited the answer...